# R - using Magick to mass read pdfs. issue with looping

Tags: r, pdf, imagemagick, ocr

I'm trying to write a script to read a series of pdfs, OCR them using the tesseract package, and then do things with the text I can extract.

So far, I'm at the following:

```
ReportDensity <- list()
AllReports <- list.files(path = "path",pattern = "*.PDF",full.names=TRUE)
```

and then I needed to call the page number for each pdf so that I can read the image data

```
for (i in seq(AllReports))
    ReportDensity[[i]] <- pdf_info(AllReports[[i]])
ReportDensity <- lapply(ReportDensity, `[[`, 2)
```

Now, what I want to do is to list each page of a pdf of a separate image file so that I can OCR it.

```
for (i in seq(AllReports))
    for (j in 1:ReportDensity[[i]])

(assign(paste0("Report_",i,"_Page_",j),image_read_pdf(AllReports[[i]],pages = ReportDensity[j])))
```

The error message I receive is:

"Error in poppler_render_page(loadfile(pdf), page, dpi, opw, upw, antialiasing,  : 
  Invalid page."

which I believe to be because I wrote the loop incorrectly. I have tested the code by manually putting in image/page numbers, and it loads correctly.

I'm hoping that the end result would be a series of image files of the form "Report_ReportNumber_PageNumber" that I could then process.

Answer (score 0):

pdfs are text mainly (most often);
i usually extract text from pdfs using python's [pdf2txt](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/), page by page run on the shell through a call to

```
i=pagenumber
```

`system(paste("pdf2txt -p", i, "-o text.txt pdffile.pdf"))`
then you can grep text from each page; flag -o can output an html or xml which you can scrap with `library(rvest)`

```
[pdfimages][2] extracts the images contained in pdfs, you can OCR those:

system(paste("pdfimages -f", i, "-l", i, "-p -png pdffile.pdf imagefile"))
```

that may output a lot of pngs from a single page, they come out numbered:

```
system(paste0("tesseract  imagefile-",i,"-006.png out6"))
```

tesseract has several parameters you must tune before getting a decent result

Comment: I'm not proficient at all in python yet, so I'm not sure how much I can do with this. That being said, this looks useful and I appreciate the reply!

Comment: are you using linux or windows? the "python" part is just a program written in python